# Walking a dog on Shabbath for leisure

Tags: halacha, shabbat, animals, muktzeh, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Is a dog owner allowed to walk their dog outside on The Shabbath Day for leisure purposes?

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/40659/  https://aish.com/walking-a-dog-on-shabbat/

Comment: For one thing, I am not clear on whether holding a leash is "carrying".

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is permitted. As dinonline writes [here](https://dinonline.org/2016/03/31/may-one-walkplay-with-a-dog-on-shabbos/)

> **The dog may be attached to a leash and walked. This may be done even
> in a place without an eruv. The leash must be kept a *tefach* [3 inches]
> above the ground, and no slack should be left to hang past the hand
> holding the leash.**
>
> Whether one may touch, pet, pick up and play with the dog is a matter
> of debate. Do we consider pet dogs *muktzeh* or are they like a toy of
> sorts that may be used? While many lean towards a stringent ruling on
> this matter, a careful reading of the sources in fact lends towards
> the lenient opinion. So while it would be preferable to refrain from
> touching, one who is lenient has who to rely on.

Similarly R Chaim Tabasky writes [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/3563) at yeshiva.co

> **It is permissible to walk a dog on a leash on Shabbat, even in an area
> that is not enclosed.** One must be careful, however, that the leash
> does not extend beyond the hand. The part of the leash which is
> between the man and the dog is considered to be carried by the dog,
> however if the leash extends over the hand by more than a "*tefach*"
> (about 4 inches) that part of the leash is being carried by the person,
> and that is not permitted.

See also [here](https://aish.com/walking-a-dog-on-shabbat/).